# digits by fabric unable to sign in in signed apk

Tags: android, signed, twitter-fabric

Hey I am using Fabric by Twitter from [this](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/sign-in-with-phone-number.html) to Sign in to a device. It was all working fine(in the debug version) until I created the signed apk and now it does not even send the OTP and stops progressing before sending the message.

```
        digitsButton = (DigitsAuthButton) findViewById(R.id.auth_button);

    authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
    Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(authConfig), new Digits.Builder().build());
    digitsButton.setAuthTheme(R.style.Theme_Material);

    authCallback = new AuthCallback() {

        @Override
        public void success(DigitsSession session, String phoneNumber) {
            firebaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(phoneNumber)) {
                        firebaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
                        startNewActivity(false, phoneNumber);

                    } else {

                        firebaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
                        startNewActivity(true, phoneNumber);

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(DigitsException error) {

        }
    };
    digitsButton.setCallback(authCallback);
    digitsButton.performClick();
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. What errors or messages are you seeing in the console or on the device?

Comment: Hey @MikeBonnell, I was trying to authenticate the user. But it just didn't work It would stop and sometimes even hanged in the signed apk.when sending the message had to remove digits authentication altogether. Thre were no error logs.

Comment: Hmm, I'm surprised there wasn't more information. If you can reproduce locally, I'd try adding debug mode: https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html to see if that gets you more information.